# Passing rails params to linked js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, scope

I've got a view with an attached js.erb file that I'm trying to use to auto-link to some ajax content. I've got the code working when it's included on the view page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  //auto opening a phase
  <% if params[:phase] %>
    auto_phase = <%= params[:phase] %>;
    //open the specified phase
      var a_id = "phase_" + auto_phase;
      $('a#'+a_id).click();
  <% else %>
    //auto open first phase
      $('a.phase_status_0').first().click(); 
  <% end %>
})
</script>
```

But when I move the code to the js.erb file that is linked via:

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "projects.js.erb" %>
<% end %>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<#<Class:0x299454c>:0x450185c>
```

Is there an easy way to allow the js.erb file to access the params from the view's url? (example: www.site.com/projects/16?phase=18)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javascript_include_tag` only allows you to include vanilla JavaScript files.

What you are probably looking for is to put your code into `_projects.js.erb` and then render it as a partial:

```
<% render 'projects.js', :locals => { :project_phase => params[:phase] } %>
```

And then replace `params[:phase]` with `:project_phase` in your js.erb file.

*Side note:*

This line:

```
auto_phase = <%= params[:phase] %>;
```

is missing quotes, so in the new file would look like:

```
auto_phase = "<%= :project_phase %>";
```

Comment: I see. I think for this instance, since it's a fairly simple application, I'll just keep the $(document).ready(function() in the main view file, but good to know for future reference. Thanks!